# Kafka - Running Tutorial, Any Scripts Causing Additional Window to Open, then close, then command return? No logs

Tags: apache-kafka, command-prompt

As in the title, I'm following the initial Kafka tutorial - have downloaded & unpacked the Kafka package and am now trying to start the Zookeeper server from the command prompt.

I'm getting the behaviour described in the title - no logs. Can anyone help?